# google.maps.Data.Geometry subtypes do not inherit from it in version 3.31

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**EDIT**: **the bug is already fixed** (see below and comments). But I guess I'll leave this here for further reference. Who knows if the bug strikes again in the future.

---

This is a weird behavior I noticed yesterday when using version `3.31` (current experimental version).

Objects such as [google.maps.Data.Point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Point) reportedly inherit from [google.maps.Data.Geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Geometry) class. So the following:

```
var Feature=new google.maps.Data.Feature({geometry:{lat:10,lng:10}});
console.log(Feature.getGeometry() instanceof google.maps.Data.Geometry);
```

should print `true`.

This is the case when using stable version `3.30`.

```js
var response,
    Feature=new google.maps.Data.Feature({geometry:{lat:10,lng:10}});
    Geometry=Feature.getGeometry();
    
document.getElementById('type').innerHTML=Geometry.getType();

if(Feature.getGeometry() instanceof google.maps.Data.Geometry) {
  response = '<u>IS</u>';
} else {
  response = '<b>IS NOT<b>';
}
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML= response;
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.30&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>

<div>Feature Type is:   <span id="type"></span>
 <br>
 Feature <span id="response"></span> an instance of <i>google.maps.Data.Geometry</i>
</div>
```

However, when using version `3.31` or `3.exp` (which is the same as of today), the result is false:

```js
var response,
    Feature=new google.maps.Data.Feature({geometry:{lat:10,lng:10}});
    Geometry=Feature.getGeometry();
    
document.getElementById('type').innerHTML=Geometry.getType();

if(Feature.getGeometry() instanceof google.maps.Data.Geometry) {
  response = '<u>IS</u>';
} else {
  response = '<b>IS NOT<b>';
}
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML= response;
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>
<div>Feature Type is:  <span id="type"></span>
  <br>
  Feature <span id="response"></span> an instance of <i>google.maps.Data.Geometry</i>
</div>
```

Is anyone else experimenting this behavior? Is it a bug? What puzzles me is that I've been using `3.exp` since, at least, 3 months ago (October 2017) and before yesterday it used to work.

**EDIT** as @xomena said, **the bug is fixed now**. Both snippets will say that `google.maps.Data.Point` is an instance of `google.maps.Data.Geometry`.

Comment: I guess the Google team made certain changes in experimental version that break this functionality. I've filed a bug on your behalf in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72094719.

Comment: @xomena hey thanks! I'm not familiar with issuetracker inner etiquette, so I keep my doubts and bug reports in SO and Github

Comment: Good news. Google fixed this bug. Now 3.31 works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help @xomena